# How to do a conditional count in noncontiguous cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following data on a spreadsheet (xlsx) (Excel 2011 14.6.4 for Mac):

```
No  Yes Yes
No  Yes Yes
No  Yes Yes
```

I am trying to count the number of "Yes" values for just A1 and C1 skipping B1 (I can't just hide/delete the B column since it's used for other formulae).

I've tried the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF((A1,C1),"Yes")
```

but I'm getting a Value error with no info on what may have gone wrong. `A1:C1` is inappropriate since I need to skip `B1`. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"Yes"),COUNTIF(C1,"Yes"))
```

The Countif() function specifically requires a range of cells. A list of cells is not a range.

 Excel Help states,

> **COUNTIF**(range, criteria)  
> range    Required. One or more cells to count, including numbers or names, arrays, or references that
>   contain numbers. Blank and text values are ignored.

Other functions, like SUM(), which can use a list will say so in the help.
Excel help for SUM() states,

> **SUM(number1,[number2],...])** 
>  The SUM function adds all the
>   numbers that you specify as arguments. Each argument can be a range, a
>   cell reference, an array, a constant, a formula, or the result from
>   another function.

Comment: Works perfectly. Any idea though why specifying cells separated by a ',' doesn't work though? It does on some versions of Excel on Windows that I've used.

Comment: @Kaleb, answer updated.